# package XX does not verify: Payload SHA256 ALT digest: BAD

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

Trying to install a package using `yum` with and without the option `--nogpgcheck` on RHEL 9.
In both cases I get the following error:

```
package XXX does not verify: Payload SHA256 ALT digest: BAD (Expected XXX != XXX)
```

I've tried to import the GPG of the provider and verified signature but result is `NOT OK DIGEST`.

I thought this could be related to `cyrpto-policies` and SHA1 being deprecated in RHEL9. This was not the case.

```
$ sudo update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1
```

I'm fairly lost to what to do.

`sudo dnf clean all` and `sudo dnf --refresh upgrade` suggested in [this Fedora forum posting](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/package-does-not-verify-payload-sha256-digest-bad/75766) didn't help.

Comment: It didnt' help.